# How can I view all libraries across a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

One request I received recently was if within one page I could list all the library folders found in the Site Collection..We would just want to see 2 fields the Site Name and the Folder Name.  Example below.

HR Contacts

Legal Contacts

Ops Contacts

Comment: are you using SharePoint Online Site or On Premise ? You can develop a component based on your Environment. You can go for a webpart if you are on On Premise or You can create a ECMA Script to get the data and render it using HTML

Comment: I am using Sharepoint enterprise

Comment: Create a WebPart and pull all the Sites under that Site Collection and also the Contacts List under those Sites. Then you can render this using HTML